# How to fix an error with implementation socket.io in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I want to use socket.io in its extension, but when I import the library, it throws the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined". I realized that this socket.io does document and window checks, however, in the background.js I can't use either the document API or the window object. I use manifest **v3**. What should I do to use sockets?

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDNGm.png)

[background.js image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPqTB.png)

Comment: You can't use it in a ManifestV3 service worker. You'll have to open a separate tab. This is yet another use case broken in ManifestV3.

Comment: @wOxxOm, but what can I do? I need to use Socket.io

Comment: Don't use ManifestV3, which is still actually half-broken, or always keep an open tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm, but the problem is the same, as due to the transition to the second version of the manifest, I will be able to use socket.io when the problem is that socket io is doing a document and window check that are not available in the background

Comment: No, in ManifestV2 you will use a standard background page script which has document and window.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to use it

Comment: @wOxxOm, still exist https://i.imgur.com/qZnMVAw.png

Comment: You're seeing an old error. Click the `clear all` button to remove it and use [background.js console](/a/10258029). Also don't forget to reload the extension.